# Set Value to a select field by its key in webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm trying to set a select field to one specific default value by it's key (one country, which i retrieve from another form), and then disable the field.

I implement hook_form_alter, i get the correct field inside the $form array, but, when i want to set the select field to one value, nothing happens. I'm trying this way:

```
 $form['#node']->webform['component'][91]['value']['#default_value'] = $country;
```

But, this does not work. Any guess on how i can achieved this, and if this is possible or the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it and it works:

```
// set default value to a D7 form field
$form['FIELD_NAME']['und'][0]['value'] = $country;

// prevent user from changing the field value
$form['FIELD_NAME']['#access'] = false;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer, but i managed to achieve what i wanted, simply by modifying $form_state.